# How to search by hierarchical taxonomy in views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view with a `Global: Combine fields` filter with some fields, one of theese fields is a hiererchical select field of a taxonomy terms. But it doesn't work.

How can I set a search box to search by text in a hiererchical select field (and other fields)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) Module and it supports for hiererchical select

> By default the module will automatically apply itself to any select
>   elements that have more than 20 options, which is a reasonable default
>   for which having Chosen will be useful. To change or disable this
>   automatic enhancement, you can change the selectors (or remove all
>   selectors) from the Apply Chosen to the following elements field on
>   the Chosen administration page.